# Multiple filter with dropdown using `Javascript` in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I Have an HTML table with with rows & columns.The columns need to filtered using drop down values.

At present the code is working upto 2 columns.

Working Scenario 1 :- If I Filter by Name Column : JOHN.

Working Scenario 2 :- If I Filter by Name Column : **JOHN** && Country Column **INDIA**.

please help me filter with more than 2 columns.

For upto 3 Filters Ex:- if Name == JOHN && Country == INDIA && Age == 80

For upto 4 Filters Ex:- if Name == JOHN && Country == INDIA && Age == 80 && Salary == 3000

```js
function SearchData() {

  var name = document.getElementById("idName").value.toUpperCase();
  var country = document.getElementById("idCountry").value.toUpperCase();
  var age = document.getElementById("idAge").value.toUpperCase();
  var salary = document.getElementById("idSalary").value.toUpperCase();

  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {

    var rowName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rowCountry = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rowAge = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rowSalary = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].textContent.toUpperCase();

    if (name != 'ALL' && country != 'ALL') {
      if (rowName == name && rowCountry == country) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } else if (rowName != '' || rowCountry != '') {
      if (name != 'ALL') {
        if (rowName == name) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      if (country != 'ALL') {
        if (rowCountry == country) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>joe</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Australia</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>alan</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>6000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select id="idName">
  <option value="all">Select Name</option>
  <option value="Jill">Jill</option>
  <option value="Eve">Eve</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="sam">sam</option>
  <option value="joe">joe</option>
  <option value="alan">alan</option>
</select>

<select id="idCountry">
  <option value="all">Select Country</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
  <option value="INDIA">INDIA</option>
  <option value="AUSTRALIA">AUSTRALIA</option>
</select>

<select id="idAge">
  <option value="all">Select Age</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
</select>

<select id="idSalary">
  <option value="all">Select Salary</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="3000">3000</option>
  <option value="4000">4000</option>
  <option value="5000">5000</option>
  <option value="6000">6000</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="SearchData();" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a loop let's assume that we would like to display a row, than check if any filter applied, than one per row decide weather it will be shown or not.

```js
const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
// save all tr
const tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

function SearchData() {

  var name = document.getElementById("idName").value.toUpperCase();
  var country = document.getElementById("idCountry").value.toUpperCase();
  var age = document.getElementById("idAge").value.toUpperCase();
  var salary = document.getElementById("idSalary").value.toUpperCase();

  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {

    var rowName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rowCountry = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rowAge = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rowSalary = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].textContent.toUpperCase();

    var isDiplay = true;

    if (name != 'ALL' && rowName != name) {
      isDiplay = false;
    }
    if (country != 'ALL' && rowCountry != country) {
      isDiplay = false;
    }
    if (age != 'ALL' && rowAge != age) {
      isDiplay = false;
    }
    if (salary != 'ALL' && rowSalary != salary) {
      isDiplay = false;
    }
    
    if (isDiplay) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }


  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>joe</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Australia</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>alan</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>6000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select id="idName">
  <option value="all">Select Name</option>
  <option value="Jill">Jill</option>
  <option value="Eve">Eve</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="sam">sam</option>
  <option value="joe">joe</option>
  <option value="alan">alan</option>
</select>

<select id="idCountry">
  <option value="all">Select Country</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
  <option value="INDIA">INDIA</option>
  <option value="AUSTRALIA">AUSTRALIA</option>
</select>

<select id="idAge">
  <option value="all">Select Age</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
</select>

<select id="idSalary">
  <option value="all">Select Salary</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="3000">3000</option>
  <option value="4000">4000</option>
  <option value="5000">5000</option>
  <option value="6000">6000</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="SearchData();" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below custom filter function. you can iterate over a row and find matching values.

```js
function myFunction(index,inputname) {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById(inputname);
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("empTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[index];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if(tr[i].style.display=="")
      {
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#empTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#empTable th, #empTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#empTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#empTable tr.header, #empTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<table id="empTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;"><input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="myFunction(0,'name')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"></th>
    <th style="width:40%;"><input type="text" id="country" onkeyup="myFunction(1,'country')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"></th>
       <th style="width:40%;"><input type="text" id="age" onkeyup="myFunction(2,'age')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"></th>
        <th style="width:40%;"><input type="text" id="salary" onkeyup="myFunction(3,'salary')" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
     <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>joe</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Australia</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>alan</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>6000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sam</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>4000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>INDIA</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is one limitation with this code because with the if check here tr[i].style.display=="" , in case we try to remove the previous filter the rows doesn't get updated as we have already assigned those rows as style.display="none". 
Steps To reproduce: Search India for Country and then Search Jon for Name. Now try updating Jon to John where it should have shown 3 rows but rather show none.
Any fix to resolve this issue?